# check the added urls

Tags: php, url, preg-match

I'm building a php system which allow users to resend their invoices that need to be rechecked,

My problem is i need to make a condition to my system so it can't accept any url expect urls that looks like the following example

```
$url = http://mydomain.com/$id/invoice/$num

http://mydomain.com/murad/invoice/6589445564555

http://mydomain.com/ludmilla/invoice/9764564252
```

code:

```
} elseif(preg_match("|^http(s)?://(www.)?mydomain.com/([a-z]+)/(.*)?$|i", $url)){
        $msg = '<div class="msg"><div class="error">'.$lang['er_01'].'</div></div>';
```

but it didn't work , Can i know how to make it work correctly ?

Comment: Why are you asking this for the third time now? and why do you absolutely want to use a regex?

Comment: What didn't work? What do you mean by `how to make it work correctly`?

Comment: @Fabian this is another ques. i want to make any condition to make my system only accept 1 type of urls when users try to add any url

Comment: @M42 show me how can i make that condition :)

Comment: I fail to see how this is different. Just use the answer from the other question to get the values for the customer name and the invoice id and check if they're valid.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you need to reverse the test and change a bit the regex, try this:

```
} elseif( ! preg_match("|^http(s)?://(www.)?mydomain.com/([a-z]+)/invoice/(\d+)$|i", $url) ){
    $msg = '<div class="msg"><div class="error">'.$lang['er_01'].'</div></div>';
```

Comment: @Dr.Mezo: What didn't work? Edit your question add more code, show some possible input and what happens versus expected result. The answer given works pretty fine for me.